# Check string for heading tags and inner numbered list level

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I need to correct a string with wrong heading-tags and missing p-tags:

```
<h3>1. Title</h3>
Text
<h3>1.1 Subtitle</h3>
Text
<h3>1.2. Subtitle</h3>
```

Should get

```
<h2>1. Title</h2>
<p>Text</p>
<h3>1.1. Subtitle</h3>
<p>Text</p>
<h3>1.2. Subtitle</h3>
```

That means every heading of a first level of the list should be a h2-tag. The second level could have the format `1.1.` or `1.1`, which should be corrected with the missing `.`
If there is no tag at all, a p-tag should be added.

```
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $text);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if(!strpos($line,"<h")) $line = '<p>'.$line.'</p>';
    $output = $output.$line;
}
```

So this adds the missing p-tags, but I don't know how to take care of the heading tags and the optional missing point of the second level.

Comment: Generally, html and regex don't mix well. I would suggest trying to find a solution that doesn't include regex.

Comment: I thought to check if the beginning of the line matches `<h3>1. ` or `<h3>1.1`, that means I have to check if there is a heading tag at the beginning followed by a digit, point and blankspace or another digit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will use a regular expression for getting the different parts, and determine what header level to use depending on the number (`h2` for `1.`, `h3` for `1.2` etc). This would work if the HTML you are parsing is really as simple as per your example. If not, I would strongly recommend that you take a look at the [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) parser instead.

```
$html = <<<EOS
<h3>1. Title</h3>
Text
<h3>1.1 Subtitle</h3>
Text
<h3>1.2. Subtitle</h3>
Text
EOS;

$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $html);

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (preg_match('/^<(\w.*?)>([\d\.]*)(.*?)</', $line, $matches)) {
        $tag    = $matches[1]; // "h3"
        $number = $matches[2]; // "1.2"
        $title  = $matches[3]; // "Subtitle"

        if ($tag == 'h3') {
            $level = preg_match_all('/\d+/', $number) + 1;
            $tag = 'h' . $level;
            if (substr($number, -1, 1) != '.')
                $number .= '.';

            $line = "<$tag>$number$title</$tag>";
        }
    }
    else {
        $line = "<p>$line</p>";
    }
    echo $line, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
<h2>1. Title</h2>
<p>Text</p>
<h3>1.1. Subtitle</h3>
<p>Text</p>
<h3>1.2. Subtitle</h3>
<p>Text</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this :

```
 $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $text);
 foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if(strpos($line,"<h") === false) $line = '<p>'.$line.'</p>';
    $output = $output.$line;
 }
```

or this

```
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $text);
foreach ($lines as $key => $line) 
{ 
   if($key%2!=0) $line = '<p>'.$line.'</p>';
   $output = $output.$line;

}
```

Comment: You souldn't compare with == , because the position of '<h' is 0 and strpos('Text') return false so false == 0 , you sould campar with ===

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$text = '<h3>1. Title</h3>
         Text 
         <h3>1.1 Subtitle</h3>
         Text
         <h3>1.2. Subtitle</h3>';
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $text);

$lines[0] = str_replace('h3','h2',$lines[0]); // Need to replace h3 to h2   only on First node
// replace a array of string
$search_str = array('.1 ', '.2 ');
$replace_str = array('.1. ', '.2. ');

foreach($lines as $line){
    if(!strchr($line,"<")){
       $line = '<p>'.$line.'</p>';
    }
$line = str_replace($search_str, $replace_str, $line);
print $line;
}
```